# Creating Nodes Of A Content Type on-the-fly While Creating A Different Content Type

Tags: nodes, entities

## Exposition

On a Drupal 7 site I have two Content Types with the following fields:

- **Scenes**

  1. Scene Name
  2. Starring (Actor's names)
  3. Streaming Link
- **Releases** (DVD Releases)

  1. Title
  2. Description
  3. *Starring* (All actor's names from all Scenes referenced)
  4. *Multiple* Scenes (Entity references to the Scene Content Type)

## My Question

Is there a Drupal 7 module or some technique that will allow me to create new Scene nodes on-the-fly *while* in the Create Release (node/add/releases) form?

## Avenues I Have Explored

- [Field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) (No way to set Scene Name or Create separate nodes)
- Node Reference + [noderefcreate](http://drupal.org/project/noderefcreate) (Creates blank Scene without prompting for the fields)
- [Inline References](http://drupal.org/project/inline_references) is an abandoned Drupal 6 module that looks like it was meant for using with nodrefcreate to add the other fields like I want.

## The Solution

Thanks to Clive's Answer, I've found [Node Connect](http://drupal.org/project/nodeconnect) which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to use the node reference field from the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references) instead of the Entity Reference once the [Node Reference Create](http://drupal.org/project/noderefcreate) module might be of some help:

> Node Reference Create is an enhancement to the nodereference autocomplete widget that allows users to reference non-existent nodes.
>
> When no matching node is selected, the new nodes are automatically created allowing for a seamless and intuitive user experience that is similar to free tagging.

I think the [Contextual Administration](http://drupal.org/project/context_admin) module might also be useful too; there's some video documentation under the title of "Automatic Node Reference on Node Create" which will probably interest you the most.

**UPDATE**

You also might want to check out the [NodeConnect module](http://drupal.org/project/nodeconnect), it doesn't append the fields of the referenced node to the original node's edit form but does this instead:

> Node Connect expands the node reference (of the references project) auto-complete field by adding a add new content and edit current content button.
>
> The add a new button will all a new node to be added via a node add form and then return the user to the original form.
>
> The edit button will take the user to the edit form of the referenced node, and return them when they are done editing.
>
> Unlike other module that have provide this functionality this module does not use popups of kind, but caches the original forms when switch to child forms. This allows for multiple levels of adding and editing

Comment: While this does create a node of the Scene type, the part I am looking for is something that prompts the user to fill in the required fields in the Scene node.  This solution creates empty Nodes of that type with only the name used.

Is there a way to insert the Scene creation fields within the Releases creation form, or otherwise prompt for input after Node Reference Create creates a Scene Node from within a Releases creation form? (node/add/releases)

Comment: As far as Contextual Administration goes, it looks like it will be useful, but will not add the Scene creation fields to the Releases creation form.

Comment: @bitfed I knew I'd seen another module for this, I've updated the answer...it's not *exactly* what you're looking for but might be a good alternative

Comment: Clive: Brilliant.  Thanks so much.  You've nailed it.  :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be accomplished with [entityreference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) + [Inline Entity Form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) modules. it will allow to add/edit scene node inside releases add/edit.

Deepak

Comment: Inline Entity Form worked for me on D7.

Answer (score 1):

another methord: [references dialog](https://drupal.org/project/references_dialog)

> This module extends reference fields like the user and node reference fields by adding links to add, edit and search for references through a dialog.